# Selenium: different frame handling between FF and Chrome?

Tags: perl, google-chrome, selenium

I have a Selenium 2.0 test system that works fine with Firefox. The pages are organized like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <frameset>  35,* rows
    <frame> 'Header' 35 rows H x full width
    <frameset>  182,* cols
      <frame> 'TOC'  remaining rows H x 182 cols W
      <frameset>  *,0,0 rows
        <frame>  'Main'  remaining rows H x remaining cols W
        <frame>  'HiddenFrame'   0 rows H x remaining cols W
        <frame>  'UploadFrame'   0 rows H x remaining cols W
```

(Please don't chew me out for this... I didn't write it and I can't change it. I just have to test it.)

Anyway, my code (Perl Selenium::Remote::Driver 0.17 language binding, 2.38.0 server) basically loads the page and then does a `$driver->switch_to_frame(); $driver->switch_to_frame('TOC');`. It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome, after successfully loading the page, it returns "Server returned status code 204 but no data" and it's not going to the TOC (navigation) frame so I can click on links. The console error message mentions "no such frame".

Does Chrome (or Selenium using Chrome) do something different with frames? Note that these are **not** *iframes*, but old-fashioned *frames*. I can change the test code to do something different based on the browser model, if necessary. Thanks!

Add: here is the top-level HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <frameset rows="35,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO" border="0">
    <frame scrolling="NO" src="title.php" noresize="" name="Header" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no">
    <frameset cols="182,*" framespacing="2" frameborder="no" border="0">
      <frame scrolling="auto" src="toc.php" name="TOC" marginwidth="2" marginheight="8" frameborder="no">
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
        <html>  ... navigation frame
          <head>
          <body>  ... links to expand/collapse categories, and page links
        </html>
      </frame>
      <frameset rows="*,0,0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
        <frame src="Welcome.php" name="Main" marginwidth="2" marginheight="10" frameborder="no">
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>  ... main content
            <head>
            <body>  ... forms, output, buttons, etc.
          </html>
        </frame>
        <frame src="javascript:''" name="HiddenFrame" frameborder="no">
        <frame src="javascript:''" name="UploadFrame" frameborder="no">
      </frameset>
    </frameset>
    <noframes> 
      <body bgcolor="#fff9f1" link="#0000ff" vlink="#0000ff" alink="#0000ff">     
        <p> Your browser does not support frames. The Administrator supports Netscape and Internet Explorer version 4.0 or later. </p> 
      </body> 
    </noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

It's a proprietary system and scripting language (not really .php) that's not publicly accessible, so I hope that's enough to figure out what's going on. Many thanks if you can spot what Chrome doesn't like, that Firefox has no problem with. Using the suggested workaround `($ele = $driver->find_element("//frame[@name='TOC']"); $driver->switch_to_frame($ele);`, I can get into the TOC frame, but I can't do the same thing for 'Main' frame.

Comment: Does the workaround shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=107) help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no difference in the frame handling between Chrome and Firefox.   I do know that sometimes you can run Firefox with "native actions" and , in theory, it might be different if you did that, but most likely it sounds like you aren't doing that.   So, I may be wrong, but in both cases, I believe Selenium most likely just uses Javascript to locate the frames.

I think the only way you are going to solve this is by writing a simple test example that reproduces the issue you think you are seeing.  You could share it on GitHub. Then, with that example as proof of the problem, I think people would be more willing to help.

Comment: Thanks for responding on this. I'll add this information to the case when I get back to working with Chrome. As I said, it's a proprietary scripting language that I can't share publicly, but maybe I can capture a copy of the produced HTML and get that to show the problem.

Comment: There is a GitHub project called 'the-internet' that you can write Selenium tests against to verify frame handling.